# How can we display a "step" inside Visual Studio build process?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build-process, build-automation

When you are monitoring the TFS build from Visual Studio (2008 or 2005), you can see where it is up to.

The issue is that I have some Post-Build custom steps I would like the developer to be able to see directly throught the UI. Those steps take some times and we can also get a "timing" of the build step.

Any idea how to have it displayed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the pattern that I normally use for adding steps to the build report in TFS 2008. (See http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/buildwallboard/ for the full example that I usually use in my Team Build talks)

Basically, the magic is that there is a custom task provided for you in TFS2008 called "BuildStep".  Here is the section where I generate and MSI installer and build the appropriate build steps in the report:

```
  <Target Name="PackageBinaries">

    <!-- create the build step -->
    <BuildStep TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
               BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
               Message="Creating Installer"
               Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'true' " >
      <Output TaskParameter="Id"
              PropertyName="InstallerStepId" />
    </BuildStep>

    <!-- Create the MSI file using WiX -->
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionRoot)\SetupProject\wallboard.wixproj"
  Properties="BinariesSource=$(OutDir);PublishDir=$(BinariesRoot);Configuration=%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavourToBuild)" >
    </MSBuild>

    <!-- If we sucessfully built the installer, tell TFS -->
    <BuildStep TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
               BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
               Id="$(InstallerStepId)"
               Status="Succeeded"
               Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'true' " />

    <!-- Note that the condition above means that we do not talk to TFS when doing a Desktop Build -->

    <!-- If we error during this step, then tell TFS we failed-->
    <OnError   ExecuteTargets="MarkInstallerFailed" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="MarkInstallerFailed">
    <!-- Called by the PackageBinaries method if creating the installer fails -->
    <BuildStep TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
               BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
               Id="$(InstallerStepId)"
               Status="Failed"
               Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)' != 'true' " />
  </Target>
```

So initially, I create the build step and save the Id of the step in a propery called InstallerStepId.  After I have performed my task, I set the status of that step to Succeeded.  If any errors occur during the step then I set the status of that step to Failed.

Good luck,

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in @Martin Woodward's great example, PackageBinaries is one of the existing [TFS build targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). If you want to use your own targets, you can use the [CallTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229474%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) task to call them from one of the known targets, e.g.,

```
<Target Name="AfterDropBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="CreateDelivery"/>
    <CallTarget Targets="CreateInventory"/>
</Target>
```

Then in your targets (e.g., CreateDelivery) use the BuildStep task as per Martin's example.