# How to have indented build steps in MSBuild/TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I understand how to do build steps using the BuildStep task in MSBuild and TFS as shown here:

[How can we display a "step" inside Visual Studio build process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226717/how-can-we-display-a-step-inside-visual-studio-build-process)

What I would like to have is indented build steps like the default MSBuild/TFS build steps display:

[image]

I reviewed the MSDN documentation, read the small section in the "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build" book, and various blogs, but none seems to show how to do the indented/hierarchical build steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a blog post how you can do that: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/10/02/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-13-Get-control-over-the-Build-Output.aspx

Comment: I was reviewing this and wanted to clarify that we're using VS2010 with TFS2008 (IT has not had a chance to upgrade us yet).  Will your solution work with TFS2008?